# swich from ubuntu (unity) lockscreen/login to gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, login-screen, lock-screen

I have Ubuntu GNOME installed on my pc and I also installed the unity shell, the problem is I seem to have lost the GNOME login screen and lock screen, is it possible to switch back from the new unity one to the original GNOME one? 
thanx

Comment: click the Ubuntu logo right of your name on the login screen

Comment: i know how to get to the shell, its the login screen i want to change (from the unity one to gnomes)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Using_units).

Comment: If anyone comes across this the solution is sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Comment: I'd add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To switch lockscreen/login to gnome, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```